# OpenCV VideoWriter outputting a zero KB video file

Tags: python, opencv

I have this code below:

```
# Setup Video capture
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(args['video_path'])
# Read a frame from the video
ret, frame = cap.read()
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)

'''
Print some information about the video
'''
print('\n#######################################')
print(f'Video Resolution: {frame.shape}')
print(f'Video FPS: {fps:.2f}')
total_num_frames = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
print(f'Total video frames: {total_num_frames}')
print('#######################################\n')

input('Press Enter to start processing video...\n')

'''
Video Writer
    - output path
    - codec
    - FPS
    - resolution (width,height)    
'''
width = frame.shape[1] #output width
height = frame.shape[0] #output height

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID') # try *'mp4v' instead of XVID
out = cv2.VideoWriter('./demo_output/demo_result.avi', fourcc, 30, (width, height))

# Set current_frame progress to 0 before main loop
current_num_frame = 0
while True:
    # Loop through each frame of the video capture
    try:
        if width < 1920 and height < 1080:
            print('Resolution too small')
            break
        elif width >=3840 and height >=2160:
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            scale_factor = 0.5
            frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0, 0), fx=scale_factor, fy=scale_factor) # interpolation=cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4
            ori_img = frame.copy()
            print('4K Res check: True')
        else:
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            print('Other res chech: True')
    except:
        print("Finished")
        cap.release()
        break

    frame = frame.copy()
    image = tensor_transform(frame)
    image = img_transform(image).unsqueeze(0)
    print('Img transformations: True')

    with torch.no_grad():
        d6 = model(image)
        print('Model output: True')

        count, pred_kpoint = counting(d6) # (540, 960), count = int(scalar)
        # point_map = generate_point_map(pred_kpoint) # (540, 960, 3)
        box_img = generate_bounding_boxes(pred_kpoint, frame) # (540, 960, 3)
        print('box_img output: True')
        # show_fidt = show_fidt_func(d6.data.cpu().numpy()) # (540, 960, 3)

        # res1 = np.hstack((ori_img, show_fidt)) # (540, 1920, 3)
        # res2 = np.hstack((box_img, point_map)) # (540, 1920, 3)
        # res = np.vstack((res1, res2)) # (1080, 1920, 3)

        cv2.putText(box_img, "Count:" + str(count), (30, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        # cv2.imwrite('./demo_output/demo.jpg', res)
        '''write in out_video'''
        out.write(box_img)
        print('Video write: True')
    current_num_frame += 1
    print(f"Pred: {int(count)}, frame: {current_num_frame} / {total_num_frames}")
```

And my goal is to read the width and height (resolution) of the video. And depending on that resolution I want to not proceed, or downscale the video or just do nothing and carry on.

On a 4K video it does not work, but it does enter the if statement since it's true. The print statements indicate that.

The 1080p video on the other hand works. It doesn't get downscaled and the VideoWriter produces a working .avi file.

If I remove the if-statements and just keep the downscale step as it was in the original video, it still does not work.

```
while True:
    # Loop through each frame of the video capture
    try:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        scale_factor = 0.5
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0, 0), fx=scale_factor, fy=scale_factor) # interpolation=cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4
        # ori_img = frame.copy()
        print('4K Res check: True')
    except:
        print("Finished")
        cap.release()
        break

    frame = frame.copy()
    image = tensor_transform(frame)
    image = img_transform(image).unsqueeze(0)
```

The original code before I messed it up was just downscaling the video and it used to work. But when I tried it with 1080p instead of 4K, the downscaling was ruining the quality. So I wanted to put a resolution check to stop it from downscaling if the video is 1080p.

One last thing is that the code does not produce and errors and everything seems to work perfectly:
[image: Program output shows that everything works as it should]

EDIT:

```
with torch.no_grad():
    d6 = model(image)

    count, pred_kpoint = counting(d6) # (540, 960), count = int(scalar)
    point_map = generate_point_map(pred_kpoint) # (540, 960, 3)
    box_img = generate_bounding_boxes(pred_kpoint, frame) # (540, 960, 3)
    show_fidt = show_fidt_func(d6.data.cpu().numpy()) # (540, 960, 3)

    res1 = np.hstack((ori_img, show_fidt)) # (540, 1920, 3)
    res2 = np.hstack((box_img, point_map)) # (540, 1920, 3)
    res = np.vstack((res1, res2)) # (1080, 1920, 3)

    cv2.putText(res, "Count:" + str(count), (30, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    # cv2.imwrite('./demo_output/demo.jpg', res)
    '''write in out_video'''
    out.write(res)
```

If I write the res variable which is a combination of outputs (this is how it was done before) then it works on both 4K and 1080P. But for my case I wanted only the box_img variable. So when I put that into out.write(), it would stop working.

My guess it has something to do with the height and width shapes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. As I suspected it was the resolution settings of the VideoWriter.

The problem was that the VideoWriter was set to write in the same resolution as the input video. The problem is that since the video is getting downscaled down the line, the two resolutions do not match.

Example:
Input Video - (3840 x 2160) 4K
Height and width of the VideoWriter was the same.

But then came the resize part and the resolution changed from 3840 x 2160 to 1920 x 1080; but the video writer was trying to write a resolution of 3840 x 2160.

So what I did was add this code at the start:

```
if inp_width >= 3840 and inp_height >= 2160:
    out_width = int(inp_width * 0.5)
    out_height = int(inp_height * 0.5)
elif inp_width == 1920 and inp_height == 1080:
    out_width = int(inp_width)
    out_height = int(inp_height)

out = cv2.VideoWriter('./demo_output/demo_result.avi', fourcc, 30, (out_width, out_height))
```

What this do is it checks the initial input video resolution and set the output resolution to the correct size. Problem solved!